# SQL subquery to database doesn't works

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview

I have problem with get dates from database in visual 2012 (C#).
I got two tables, WORKERS and JOBS.
jobs columns: job_id, job_desc, wor_id
workers columns: work_id, wor_name, wor_login

I need to fill datagridview with rows from job for worker with specified id:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource= kd.dat_table("select * from jobs where wor_id=(Select work_id from workers where wor_login= ANONYMOUS");
```

My method dat_table:

```
public DataTable dat_table(String zapytanie)
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            con.Open();

        using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(
        zapytanie, con))
        {

            DataTable t = new DataTable();
            a.Fill(t);

            return t;

        }
```

this query works in SQL Manager.

> dataGridView1.DataSource= kd.dat_table("select * from jobs);

works too.

Sorry for bad English!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to refactor using a join:

```
select j.* 
from jobs j 
inner join workers w on w.work_id = j.wor_id
where w.wor_login='ANONYMOUS'
```

You were also missing the literal quotes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use IN clause and second if wor_login is string then try to put under single quote.

```
select * from jobs where wor_id in (Select work_id from workers where wor_login= 'ANONYMOUS'"
```